# How to let user pick the data in R-shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I have a data frame that shows the historical sales of several products:

```
# A tibble: 1,430 x 4
   date           prod1      prod2      prod3
   <date>         <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     
 1 2018-01-01     86405      79841      79527   
 2 2018-01-02     187858     151150     110973   
 3 2018-01-03     165850     128996     126793
 4 2018-01-04     151554     96010      96063
 5 2018-01-05     158725     152791     112768
 6 2018-01-06     107586     110958     69742
 7 2018-01-07     325143     216590     156337
 8 2018-01-08     128492     71977      103863
 9 2018-01-09     142117     75013      107610
10 2018-01-10     182920     90451      125992
```

I want to create an interactive plot tool that plots dates on the x-axis and sales on the y-axis. The user should choose what product to forecast using a `selectInput()`. If the user chooses `prod3` then the app should plot `date` vs `prod3`.

This is what I've done so far:

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
        # Application title
        titlePanel("Plotting tool"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                selectInput(inputId = "prod",
                            label = "Select product group to plot:",
                            choices = c("prod1","prod2","prod3"), 
                            selected = NULL,
                            multiple = FALSE,
                            selectize = TRUE,
                            width = NULL,
                            size = NULL)
                ),
        # Show a plot of the raw data
        mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "plot"))
        )
    )

   server <- function(input, output) {        
    
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
          title <- "Time series of raw data"

          chosen_prod <- input$prod

          # plot time series
        
          plot(df$ds, df$chosen_prod)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However I get the error: `"Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: chosen_prod."` My understanding is that `input$prod` returns a string, so `df$chosen_prod` should just return the desired column values. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"chosen_prod" is not a column in df. Try this instead.

```
plot(df$ds, df[[chosen_prod]])
```

Comment: This actually worked. Why did not my syntax work? When I print out `df$chosen_prod` I obtain the same output as when printing out `df[[chosen_prod]]`

Comment: `df$prod1` is the same as `df[["prod1"]]`.  However if `chosen_prod = "prod1"`, then, while you cannot access the `prod1` column of `df` with this `df$chosen_prod`, you can do so with `df[[chosen_prod]]`